# Is it possible to increase the line spacing for captions to 1.5 with kable?

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown, kable

As the title suggests, i am having trouble trying to set the line spacing for my table captions to 1.5 with the kable package while knitting the document to PDF with RMarkdown.

As of now, my codes looks like this:

```
kable(
  table1,
  booktabs = T,
  align = 'l',
  caption = "A very very very very very very very very very long caption that should have line spacing of 1.5."
) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = T)
```

Thanks in advance! :)

I've tried changing the spacing: to 1.5 under the YAML header but it is not reflected in the tables produced with kable()